# Is there anyway to run the python interpreter from sublime text 3?

Tags: python, text, editor

I want to be able to run the python intpreter from inside sublime text so I can run simple snippets of code. Is there any easy way of doing this? Or do I have to open it in another window?

Answer (score 0):

try installing Terminal plugin and run python from sublime text

Answer (score 0):

Yes its very simple by using this plugin. You can run other language interpreter too.
[Sublime Repl](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL)

Install it using package control and set the settings according to documentation. After installation, you can access the repl by going to `Tools -> command pallet`. Type in `sublimerepl`, there you will find for python.